# Tomcat autoredeploy not working in legacyAppBase

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat10

I have old java application. I need to deploy it into tomcat 10. **It works only if I move file to webapps-javaee and restart tomcat.** But I do not want to manually restart tomcat each time.

If I only copy new .war file into webapps-javaee folder(without tomcat restart), tomcat does nothing. Also nothing in logs.

Is there a way to use tomcat autoDeploy feature in webapps-javaee folder?

My server.xml configuration looks like this:

```
  <Host 
    name="localhost" 
    appBase="webapps" 
    legacyAppBase="webapps-javaee" 
    unpackWARs="true" 
    autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>
```